# attempt to call field 'replicate_commands' (a nil value)

Tags: redis, lua, jedis

I use jedis + lua to eval script, here is my lua script:

```
    redis.replicate_commands()
    local second = redis.call('TIME')[1]
    local currentKey = KEYS[1]..second
    if redis.call('EXISTS', currentKey) == 0 then
        redis.call('SETEX', currentKey, 1, 1)
        return 1
    else
        return redis.call('INCR', currentKey)
    end
```

As I use 'Time', it reports error:**Write commands not allowed after non deterministic commands**.
after searching on internet, I add 'redis.replicate_commands()' as first line of lua script, but it still reports error:**ERR Error running script (call to f_c89a6ee8ad732a325e530f4a69226851cde302e2): @user_script:1: user_script:1: attempt to call field 'replicate_commands' (a nil value)**

Does `replicate_commands` need arguments or is there a way to solve my problem?

redis version:3.0

jedis version:2.9

lua version: I don't know where to find

Comment: The error message message is telling you that `replicate_commands` doesn't exist within `redis`.

Comment: `redis.replicate_commands()` has been added in a version of Redis that is later than yours (v4 iirc). Consider upgrading your Redis server to a newer version.

Comment: ok, thank you.  I will pass time as argument instead of callling `Time`

Answer (score 1):

The error **attempt to call field 'replicate_commands' (a nil value)** means `replicate_commands()` doesn't exists in the `redis` object. It is a Lua-side error message.

`replicate_commands()` was introduced until Redis 3.2. See [EVAL - Replicating commands instead of scripts](https://redis.io/commands/eval#replicating-commands-instead-of-scripts). Consider upgrading.

The first error message (**Write commands not allowed after non deterministic commands**) is a redis-side message, you cannot call write-commands (like SET, SETEX, INCR, etc) after calling non-deterministic commands (like SPOP, SCAN, RANDOMKEY, TIME, etc).

> A very important part of scripting is writing scripts that are pure functions. 
>   Scripts executed in a Redis instance are, by default, propagated to
>   replicas and to the AOF file by sending the script itself -- not the
>   resulting commands.

This is so if the Redis server is restarted, playing again the AOF log, or also if replicated in a slave, the script should deliver the same dataset.

This is why in Redis 3.2 `replicate_commands()` was introduced. And starting with Redis 5 scripts are always replicated as effects -- as if `replicate_commands()` was called when the script started. But for versions before 3.2, you simply cannot do this.

Therefore, either upgrade to 3.2 or later, or pass `currentKey` already calculated to the script from the client instead.

Note that creating `currentKey` dynamically makes your script single-instance-only.

> All Redis commands must be analyzed before execution to determine
>   which keys the command will operate on. In order for this to be true
>   for EVAL, keys must be passed explicitly. This is useful in many ways,
>   but especially to make sure Redis Cluster can forward your request to
>   the appropriate cluster node.
>
> Note this rule is not enforced in order to provide the user with
>   opportunities to abuse the Redis single instance configuration, at the
>   cost of writing scripts not compatible with Redis Cluster.

Finally, the Lua version at Redis 3.0.0 is [Lua 5.1.5](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/3.0.0/deps/lua/src/lua.h), same as all the way up to Redis 6 RC1.

Comment: This was pretty much answered before in comments, but extended here for other SO users.